# Positioning the buttons in div tag under the anchor element

Tags: html, css, button, video, absolute

```
    <div class="row">
     <div class="card px-3">
          <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
               <HeaderTemplate>
                    <div id="video-gallery" class="row lightGallery">
               </HeaderTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <a class="image-tile col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-md-4 col-6" href='<%#Eval("VideoURL").ToString() %>'>
                         <img src='<%# getYouTubeThumbnail(Eval("VideoURL").ToString()) %>' alt="thumb image"/>
                         <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
                              <img src="../panel/images/lightbox/play-button.png" alt="thumb image">
                         </div>                                                           
                    </a>

                    <%--i want to put here two buttons. delete and edit--%>
                   <div>
                       <a href='<%# "Video.aspx?Edit="+Eval("VideoID")%>' class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</a>
                       <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href='<%# "Video.aspx?Delete="+Eval("VideoID")%>' class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</a>
                   </div>

               </ItemTemplate>
               <FooterTemplate>
                    </div>
               </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>
     </div>
</div>
```

i want to create delete and edit button under the video but theese buttons appears right side of video
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqq0f.jpg)
any idea?

Comment: wrap `<a class="image-tile col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-md-4 col-6" href='<%#Eval("VideoURL").ToString() %>'>` inside `div`

Comment: same result. buttons still appears right side

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/#050505" />
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="">Edit</a>
    <a href="">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this code.